# Cannot vertically scroll items in Grid view

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, navigation-drawer

I am working in an E-Commerce application. All products in the layout are arranged in Grid View. I have this problem that I cannot scroll the Grid View items, neither in an emulator nor in a phone. But when I use my desktop keyboard 'down arrow button', then it goes to the lower items and works perfectly. But when I use mouse scroller, it doesn't scroll down in an emulator. Even in my real-time phone, I can't scroll down through items.

And suppose if I select an item and press enter then it goes to my next activity as required, but when I click from Mouse, it doesn't select the item. And similarly in real time phone also, it doesn't select by tapping on the item. In short, only the keyboard control works in an emulator, in real time phone, clicks and scrolls are not working. 
Can anyone tell me whats the problem here?

Comment: did you use static images on list view ?

Comment: Its a grid view. And yes, for now I am using static images only.

Comment: check the image sizes it may be big in size in 1 or 2 Mb so use some image with small size.

Comment: Every image is like 12-15 kb

Answer (score 0):

Add **android:clickable="true"**  in parent layout in your gridview xml file

Comment: Doesnt work. I have a navigation drawer too in the same layout. So when I remove the navigation drawer, it works. But with Navigation drawer, it doesnt.